# VBA The object you entered is not a valid recordset property

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, adodb

Ok so what I am trying to do is assign a ADODB.Recordset to a ListBox in VBA. I am getting the Error: "The object you entered is not a valid recordset property".. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: adoConn is valid and set somewhere else in the code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
' Error Management
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

Dim adoRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlStmt As String

' Create the SQL statement
sqlStmnt = "SELECT GroupName FROM tblGroups"

' Execute the statement
adoRS.Open sqlStmnt, adoConn

' Add items to the lstGroups
If (adoRS.RecordCount <> 0) Then
    Set lstGroups.Recordset = adoRS
End If

' Clean up
adoRS.Close
Set adoRS = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
' Clean up
If (adoRS.State = adStateOpen) Then
    adoRS.Close
End If

Set adoRS = Nothing

If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Source & "-->" & Err.Description, , "Error"
End If
End Sub
```

This is how ADO is opened

```
Public Sub openConnection()
' The path to the database
Dim strDBPath As String
strDBPath = "C:\Users\Vincent\****\****\"

' The database name to connect to
Dim strDBName As String
strDBName = "Permissions_be.accdb"

' Full path to the database
Dim strDBFull As String
strDB = strDBPath & "\" & strDBName

' Instantiate an ADO object
Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection

' Connect to database
With adoConn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Mode = adModeShareDenyNone
    .Open (strDBPath & strDBName)
End With
End Sub
```

**Update**
So if anyone comes across this problem on Access 2010/13.
- Set the list box to a values list.
- Then on the VBA side loop through the recordset

```
' Add items to the lstGroups
If (adoRS.RecordCount <> 0) Then

    Do While Not adoRS.EOF
        ' This is how to add two columns to one listbox if you need only
        ' one then put only the (adoRS.Fields(0))
        lstGroups.AddItem (adoRS.Fields(0) & ";" & adoRS.Fields(1))
        adoRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    lstGroups.Requery
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
Set lstGroups.Recordset = adoRS
```

If you look at the documentation you will notice that the is not a "Recordset" property in the list.

There is a property of the ListBox called List and it accepts a variant array. You can get the values from the record set and put them into an array and then onto the List.

Something like

```
' Add items to the lstGroups
If (adoRS.RecordCount <> 0) Then
    lstGroups.List= adoRS.GetRows
End If
```

I did not test any of this but it might get you in the right track.

Also if you do not get it to work with the list this link has a very good example on how to add them one by one
[enter link description here](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut10pfv.htm)

Comment: I know it's more than likely that one line causing this very vague error. However in trying your solution I now get a Compile Error-->Method or data member not found

Comment: When you press the dot after your listbox and your recorset do you get intelisense ?

Comment: yes, I do but that is not an option.. if it matters this is on access 2010 and needs to be compatible to 2013 as well

Comment: I see it was my mistake; I did not know you were in access and you are right there is not that option there. Try the other one when you add one by one.

Comment: But adding one by one requires me change the ListBox to a Value List which fired another error about read only or something like that. Is that the route I really should be going though?

Comment: i.e. I removed this from the post before but I had something like this
        Do While Not adoRS.EOF
            lstGroups.AddItem (adoRS.Fields(0))
            adoRS.MoveNext
        Loop

Comment: So I got it working based on what you said. Pointed me to the right answer. Now it works with onLoad and I can get new entries in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how do you set you adoConn ? should be something like below :-

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 
Set adoConn= New ADODB.Connection

 With adoConn
     .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
     .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
     .Properties("Data Source").Value = "10.******"
     .Properties("User ID").Value = "*****readonly"
     .Properties("Password").Value = "*****readonly"
     .Open
 End With
```